# How can I adjust the spacing between the elements that are in my toolbar?

Tags: html, css, toolbar, spacing

I have created a toolbar and I have 3 list elements: "Home", "Contacts", "About Me".
Currently, they are side by side with borders separating them, however I would like to give spacing between the elements. My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="Nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="Toolbar">Home</li>
        <li id="Toolbar">Contacts</li>
        <li id="Toolbar">About Me</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a margin to each `li`

```
.Nav li{
   margin: 0px 3px; /* Adjust the px to meet your needs */
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/6Mc9W/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can space out elements. Look into the [CSS Box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) if you havent heard of it before. These ideas are used all throughout web development and it is best to read up on and understand this rather than just getting some css from online without understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

I also would like to point out that all of your list items have the same id. You can only have one element on a page that has that id. And seeing that you gave the whole list a class name, you should just get rid of the id's all together.